# UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged works just for the first DatePicker on the page

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datepicker

property I am using WPF and MVVM, and have two DatePicker such as below in my page.The `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` works just for the first one and when I change the Date in the second one, the Data binded to it doesn't change.

```
<DatePicker Grid.Column="1" Height="25" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{x:Null}" Text="{Binding UDC.StartDate, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, StringFormat={}{0:dd/MM/yyyy}}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="22,90,0,0" Name="dtStartDate" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
<DatePicker Grid.Column="1" Height="25" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{x:Null}" Text="{Binding UDC.EndDate, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, StringFormat={}{0:dd/MM/yyyy}}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="22,130,0,0" Name="dtEndDate" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
```

I searched for a solution but didn't get any result how to solve this problem.

UDC is an object of Entity like this

```
UDC
{
public int ID { get; set; }
public String Name { get; set; }
public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

All other bindings work perfectly , just the **EndDate** doesn't return any value from view.

Comment: How does the `UDC` object look like?

Comment: Using your code, as expected, both `StartDate` and `EndDate` are set

Comment: Yes But I really don't know why StartDate works fine and EndDate doesn't

Answer (score 1):

You need to make UDD implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx). Then you will need to change the setters of Start and EndDate to call OnPropertyChanged.

The other thing is see is that in your XAML, it's UDC, but in the C#, it's UDD. I don't know if that's a typo in the post, or the code.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found the answer myself. The problem was that I had binded the **Text** property of DatePicker instead of **SelectedDate**. When I changed my Xaml file to this, everything worked fine.

```
<DatePicker Validation.ErrorTemplate="{x:Null}" Grid.Column="1" Height="25" SelectedDate="{Binding UDC.StartDate,ValidatesOnDataErrors=False, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, StringFormat={}{0:dd/MM/yyyy}}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="22,48,0,0" Name="dtStartDate" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />

<DatePicker Validation.ErrorTemplate="{x:Null}" Grid.Column="1" Height="25" SelectedDate="{Binding UDC.EndDate,ValidatesOnDataErrors=False, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, StringFormat={}{0:dd/MM/yyyy}}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="22,85,0,0" Name="dtEndDate" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
```

Comment: Ha, I thought of suggesting that, but looking around the web I saw other examples binding to Text. I've never used the plain WPF DatePicker myself. Glad you figured it out!